# Adding Data into Mongo Array through Express.JS Router

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to add data from request params into MongoDb Array. My schema looks like this

```
var studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: {type: String},
    roll_num: {type: String},
    experiences: [{
        experienceTitle: String,
        Employer: String,
        fromYear: Number,
        toYear: Number
    }]
});
```

So far, I am able to add data into `first_name` & `roll_num` through simple express router which looks like this

```
router.post('/createStudent',(req, res, next) => {
    var newStudent = new student({
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        roll_num: req.body.roll_num,
    });
    newStudent.save((err, student) => {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).json({errmsg: err});
        }
        else{
            res.status(200).json({msg: student});
        }
    })
});
```

I want to add data into `experiences` array. I have written some functions to achieve this but so far I have only been able to create student with empty `experiences` array.

Comment: `I have written some functions to achieve this` show one. Print out your `req.body`

Comment: @hoangdv i used `$push` function but the object created in my db looks like this
`{
    "msg": {
        "_id": "5cd43d92423509175c24d54e",
        "experiences": [],
        "__v": 0
    }
}`

Comment: Show your `req.body`. Or try this `var newStudent = new student({
  first_name: "hoangdv",
  roll_num: "hoangdv",
  experiences: [{
    experienceTitle: "hoangdv next",
    Employer: "hoangdv next",
    fromYear: 18,
    toYear: 18
  }]
});`

Comment: the request body looks like this
`{ '{\n\tfirst_name': ' "testFirstName",\n\troll_num= "R0000",\n\texperiences= [\n\t{\n\t\texperienceName= "testExp1",\n\t\texperienceEmployer= "testEmpl",\n\t\tfromYear= 1994,\n\t\ttoYear= 1995\n\t},\n\t{\n\t\texperienceName= "testExp2",\n\t\texperienceEmployer= "testEmp3",\n\t\tfromYear= 1996,\n\t\ttoYear= 1997\n\t}\n\t]\n}' }`
i used Postman to post data

Comment: hmm, provide `console.log(req.body)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
//...

const student = new Student({
    first_name: "testFirstName",
    roll_num: "R0000",
    experiences: [{
        experienceName: "testExp1",
        experienceEmployer: "testEmpl",
        fromYear: 1994,
        toYear: 1995
    }, {
        experienceName: "testExp2",
        experienceEmployer: "testEmp3",
        fromYear: 1996,
        toYear: 1997
    }]
});

await student.save();

//...
```

Comment: i have. it works. but i want to add `experiences` from `req.body.experiences`. so far i have tried
`student.update({roll_num: newStudent.roll_num},{
      $push: {experiences: {$each: req.body.experiences}}
  });`
but it still leaves the `experiences` array empty.

Comment: You should only use each if `req.body.experiences` is an array of experiences. However, if it is a single experience object, you should do this instead: `{ $push: {experiences: req.body.experiences} }`.